# Left margin flush for itemize's item labels in LaTeX

Tags: lists, line-breaking, indentation

I am trying to get the item label to flush with the left margin of the page width within `itemize`, i.e.:

This is my sentence. Here are my items:

1. ITEMNAME

   - notice my list definition is indented
2. ITEMNAME

   - but my item labels are all flush with the left margin and not sticking out of it

Note I am using `\item[ITEMNAME] \hfill \\` to create a definition style item with a linebreak between keyword and definition, as demonstrated above. How can I get the desired flush that only affects the item's label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to perform your list management. Here's an example of what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    [align=left,style=nextline,leftmargin=*,labelsep=\parindent,font=\normalfont]
  \item[FIRST ITEM] Note that my list definition is not indented
  \item[SECOND ITEM] This one is also not indented and the description
    is long enough to span two lines.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `description` performs:

- `align=left`: Ensures a left-aligned item label;
- `leftmargin=*`: Left margin of `description` is flush with left margin of text block;
- `style=nextline`: Automates the process of using `\hfill \\`;
- `labelsep=\parindent`: The gap between the label and the start of the item is `\labelsep`, which is set to be the same as the regular paragraph indent.
- `font=\normalfont`: This modifies the default **bold** font of the `description` item to `\normalfont`.

If need be, you can also create a new list environment to perform these "optional settings" automatically. For this, see `\newlist` and `\setlist` in the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (section **7 Cloning the basic lists**, p 10).

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was only used to emphasize the text block boundaries within the example.